# Converting a 16-bit decimal number to other bases using NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am having some issues implementing a proper decimal to binary, octal, and hex conversion using NASM assembly. I have most of the code as follows, which I know has some issues that I'm still working on getting fixed. I have commented relevant information in the code.

```
    %include "io.mac"
    .STACK 100H
    .DATA
    msg1        db "Please enter a positive integer (max 16 bits): ",0
    msg2        db "The binary (base-2) representation of the number is: ",0
    msg3        db "The octal (base-8) representation of the number is: ",0
    msg4        db "The hex (base-16) representation of the number is: ",0
    msg5        db "A",0 ;These will be implemented when I get the 
    msg6        db "B",0 ;hexadecimal loop working to change 10, 11, 
    msg7        db "C",0 ;etc. to their hex equivalents.
    msg8        db "D",0
    msg9        db "E",0
    msg10       db "F",0

    .UDATA
    num1            resw 1
    quotient        resw 1
    remainder       resw 1

    .CODE
    .STARTUP
    PutStr msg1
    nwln
    GetInt [num1]

    nwln
    PutStr msg2
    nwln
    mov AX, [num1]      
    sub BH, BH

    binary_loop:
    push AX 
    mov BH, byte 2 
    div BH ;All loops output the remainders in reverse order at the moment.
    mov [remainder], AH ;I was thinking of maybe moving the remainder value
    PutInt [remainder] ;to a stack then calling it at the end of the loop,
    mov [quotient], AL ;when the quotient value is zero. However,  
    mov AX, [quotient] ;I do not know enough to make that work. Any help
    cmp [quotient], byte 0 ;would be greatly appreciated
    jz binary_done ;Could also be je, as both do the same thing
    loop binary_loop

    binary_done:
    nwln
    PutStr msg3
    nwln
    mov AX, [num1]
    sub BH, BH      

    octal_loop:     
    push AX
    mov BH, byte 8
    div BH
    mov [remainder], AH
    PutInt [remainder]
    mov [quotient], AL
    mov AX, [quotient]
    cmp [quotient], byte 0
    jz octal_done
    loop octal_loop

    octal_done:
    nwln
    PutStr msg4
    nwln
    mov AX, [num1]      
    sub BH, BH  

    hex_loop:
    push AX
    mov BH, byte 16
    div BH
    mov [remainder], AH
    PutInt [remainder]
    mov [quotient], AL
    mov AX, [quotient]
    cmp [quotient], byte 0
    jz done
    loop hex_loop

    done:
    .EXIT
```

Current output for a test 16-bit number of 155:
Binary: 11011001
Octal: 332
Hex: 119

Answer (score 2):

Your code has 3 main problems:

- It displays digits in the reverse order
- It displays hexadecimal digits as integers (e.g. 0xB is displayed as 11)
- It's extremely badly commented (assembly is NOT a high level language)

Your code also has other issues:

- Not making effective use of registers (storing things in slower variables instead)
- Code duplication - a single routine that accepts "base" as an input would halve the size of the code
- Abusing macros ("language within a language"); which makes it harder to understand the code (e.g. no way for me to tell if `PutInt` is a function call or inline code, or which registers it uses/trashes) and makes it impossible to optimise the instructions around it correctly

For the first problem, the best approach is to build a string in memory in reverse order, and then print the resulting string. For the second problem you need to stop using `PutInt` - each digit should be converted to a character.

For example (32-bit 80x86, NASM, untested):

```
;Convert unsigned integer to string
;
;Input
; eax = integer
; ebx = base
;
;Output
; edi = address of string
;
;Trashed
; eax,edx

    section .bss
tempString: resb 33              ;Worst case string size is 32 digits
                                 ; (for base2), plus string terminator
tempStringEnd:
    section .text

convertIntegerToString:
    mov byte [tempStringEnd-1],0 ;Store string terminator
    mov edi,tempStringEnd-2      ;edi = address to store last character

.nextDigit:
    xor edx,edx                  ;edx:eax = current value
    div ebx                      ;eax = new current value, edx = next digit
    add dl,'0'                   ;dl = character for next digit maybe
    cmp dl,'9'                   ;Is the character correct?
    jbe .gotChar                 ; yes
    add dl,'A'-'0'-10            ; no, fix it up
.gotChar:
    mov [edi],dl                 ;Store the character
    dec edi                      ;edi = address for next character
    test eax,eax                 ;Is the current value zero?
    jne .nextDigit               ; no, do the next digit

    ret                          ;Done, EDI = address of completed string
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution, I will implement this into my language and let you know if I have any questions. I just started working with Assembly after a few high-level languages like Python, Java, and C++, which is why I still have high-level tendencies in coding.